# Pandas column values group to column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

So let's say I have this dataframe

```
data = [['MS', 'Boston', 'emergency', 'hname11'], ['MS', 'Boston', 'emergency', 'hname47'], ['MS', 'Boston', 'normal', 'hname72'], ['MS', 'Cambridge', 'emergency', 'hname32'], ['FL', 'Miami', 'normal', 'hname67'], ['CA', 'Los Angeles', 'emergency', 'hname91']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['state', 'city', 'status', 'name'])
df
state   city        status      name
0   MS  Boston      emergency   hname11
1   MS  Boston      emergency   hname47
2   MS  Boston      normal      hname72
3   MS  Cambridge   emergency   hname32
4   FL  Miami       normal      hname67
5   CA  Los Angeles emergency   hname91
```

So I need to count the emergency and normal values for each city and put them as a column, like this

```
state    city          emergency_count    normal_count
MS       Boston        2                  1
MS       Cambridge     1                  0
FL       Miami         0                  1
CA       Los Angeles   1                  0
```

My goal is to have just one descriptive row for each city and not several rows with splitted information.
So so far I've been using groupby and I get almost what I need

```
df.groupby(['state', 'city'])['status'].value_counts().reset_index(name='total')
state   city        status      total
0   CA  Los Angeles emergency   1
1   FL  Miami       normal      1
2   MS  Boston      emergency   2
3   MS  Boston      normal      1
4   MS  Cambridge   emergency   1
```

But I'm unable to create the columns with the sum values of the emergency and normal statuses for each city.

Comment: I accepted an answer, but I'd like to share this link shared by @jezrael that was actually quite useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please groupby `city` and `state`, value_counts `status` and `unstack`. Then rename columns

```
df2=df.groupby(['state','city'])['status'].value_counts().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)

df2.columns=['state','city','emergency_count','normal_count']
df2
```

Output

[image]